# Does the covariant derivative of a derivative of the metric vanish?

Tags: differential-geometry, supergravity

The title holds the main question. For a little more backgroud:

In a calculation I keep coming across terms of the form
$$ D_M \partial_N e_P^A \overset{?}{=} 0$$
where $e_P^A$ is the vielbein and $D_M$ is the covariant derivative *including* both the spin *and* the affine connection, i.e. the vielbein postulate reads $D_M e_P^A = 0$.

Generally, I would not expect the expression to vanish, but the again I know little about the more involved machinery of differential geometry.

Comment: Which reference are you reading?

Comment: which of these indices are space-time indices? assuming $M,N,P$ (which you would normally denote by greek letters), I don't see why that equation should hold (but I'm far from an expert)

Comment: The context is pure 6-dimensional supergravity. That's also why it is latin letters instead of greek ones. As @Christoph suggested, $M, N, P$ are the spacetime indices, while $A$ is a local frame index.

Comment: @Qmechanic as references I use the book by Freedman and van Proyen as well as Wess and Bagger.

Comment: It is the vielbein postulate shown in eq. (7.101) in the book Supergravity by Freedman and van Proeyen. You might understand its proof by reading that page in the book.